# How to Stop audio from playing

Tags: kivy

i found this gist on the net that helped my kivy app to stream audios online perfectly, but the app fails when i try to stop it from playing. here is the code..

```
def play(self,name):
    print 'playing'
    from jnius import autoclass
    from time import sleep
    MediaPlayer = autoclass('android.media.MediaPlayer')
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer()
    mPlayer.setDataSource('{}'.format(self.source))
    mPlayer.prepare()
    duration = mPlayer.getDuration()
    if self.ids.play_stop.text =='Play':
        # mPlayer.prepare()
        print 'play'
        self.ids.play_stop.text = 'Stop'
        mPlayer.start()
        # print 'current position:', mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()
        sleep(int(duration))
    elif self.ids.play_stop.text =='Stop':
        print 'stop'
        self.ids.play_stop.text = 'Play'
        # sleep(3)
        mPlayer.pause()
```

any workaround please??

Comment: try replacing mPlayer.pause() with mPlayer.stop().Bcz mPlayer.stop() should work in most of the states [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: also set your log level to 2 and run `buildozer android logcat > log.txt` and exit when app crashes.